# When string.lenght() is 0 throw an exception

Tags: java, string, exception

I have the following exercise to resolve:

In this exercise you're going to create two methods that deal with `exceptions`. One of the methods is the `main()` method, which will call another method.

If an exception is thrown in the other method, `main()` must deal with it. A `finally` statement will be included to indicate that the program has completed. The method that `main()` will call will be named `reverse`, and it will reverse the order of the characters in a `String`. If the `String` contains no characters, reverse will propagate an exception up to the `main()` method.

1. Create a class called `Propagate` and a `main()` method, which will remain empty for now.
2. Create a method called `reverse`. It takes an argument of a `String` and returns a `String`.
3. In `reverse`, check whether the `String` has a length of 0 by using the `String.length()` method. If the length is 0, the `reverse` method will throw an exception.
4. Now include the code to reverse the order of the `String`. Because this isn't the main topic of this chapter, the reversal code has been provided, but feel free to try it on your own.

   String reverseStr = "";
   for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;--i) { 
       reverseStr += s.charAt(i); }
   return reverseStr;
5. Now in the `main()` method you will attempt to call this method and deal with any potential exceptions. Additionally, you will include a `finally` statement that displays when `main()` has finished.

The problem is that even if `String.length()` is 0 the exception is not thrown:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;

public class TryAndCatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter: ");
        String entry = keyboard.next();
        try {
            if (entry.length() == 0) {
            }
        }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println("String can't have 0 characters: " + e.getMessage());

        }
        System.out.println("The reverse String is : " + TryAndCatch.reverse(entry));

        keyboard.close();
    }

    static String reverse(String text) {

        String reverseString = "";

        for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            reverseString += text.charAt(i);

        }

        return reverseString;
    }

}
```

Comment: Of course the exception is not thrown. Your code literally *does nothing* when `entry.length() == 0`.

Comment: And it is always 0 when you start the applikation.

Comment: The exception is not the default behavior of `String.length()`, you need to throw it yourself. And you probably don't want to reverse it in that case

Comment: OK, where do I start? 1. you should not use .next() but .nextLine(); 2. String has an .isEmpty() method; 3. the exercise is bad from the start (how does main() handle the exception?); etc etc

Comment: Read the problem statement again. The reverse function has to throw an exception which is caught in the main method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. This should give you Exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    String entry = keyboard.nextLine();
    keyboard.close();
    if (entry.length() == 0) {
        throw new Exception("Exception Found");
    }
    else {
        String reverse = reverse(entry);
        if (reverse.length() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Exception Found");                
        }
        else {
            // Do your Code                
            System.out.println(reverse);
        }
    }
}

static String reverse(String text) {
    String reverseString = "";
    for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverseString += text.charAt(i);
    }
    return reverseString;
}
```

And use **nextLine()** instead of **next()**

Comment: You should close the Scanner before the exception too. In the main like this, this's not a big deal but if the program keep existing, this is not good

Comment: Agreed. @AxelH. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is helpful but the exception needs to be propagated from reverse method to main method.

```
package exceptions.examples;

public class Reverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        
        String reverse = "", reversedString; 
        
        try {
            reversedString = reverseme(reverse);    
            System.out.println("Reversed String : "+reversedString );
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("Finished!");
        }
    }
    
    public static String reverseme(String reverse) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        
        String reversedString = ""; 
        if(reverse.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length cannot be zero!");
        }
        
        for(int i = reverse.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reversedString += reverse.charAt(i);            
        }
            
        return reversedString;
        
    }

}
```